# How can you access to veracrypt GUI and CLI commands on the same linux system?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, veracrypt

I tried installing veracrypt GUI along side command line version but it simply replaces the current veracrypt installation.

The issue is I very much value the usage that both offer.

Has anyone tried to do this? I am using Linux Fedora 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Veracrypt has a `-t` option that forces it to use the text-based interface even if the GUI is available.  From `veracrypt -h`:

> -t, --text
>
> Use text user interface. Graphical user interface is used by default if  available. This option must be specified as the first argument.